# Crear un botón (math.random) para seleccionar un dato de un archivo JSON y seleccionarlo

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, random

Mi problema viene cuando tengo que crear un botón en el header que haga de selector random a partir de un archivo JSON (utilizaría el ID único de cada uno para seleccionarlo y mostrarlo en una sección de la página).

Os dejo el código donde tengo que mostrar ese resultado además de ser la App principal.

Explicación rápida, tenemos unos items, que podemos seleccionar y mostrar en un "div" de favoritos donde se van mostrando los que vamos seleccionando de la lista. Todo eso funciona correctamente. Pero quiero crear un botón que seleccione varios items al azar de esa lista de JSON, su ID es el propio item "id".

Dejo también adjunto el JSON

Sé que no es difícil, pero me encuentro bloqueado y no salgo de esta tontería, pero quiero ver las mejores maneras, o las que podéis enseñarme a realizar...gracias de antemano chicos!!

```
export default class UserList extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            voices: [],
            addToFav: false,
            favorites: [],
            tags: '',
            favState: false
        };

        this.onToggle = addToFav => {
            this.setState({
                addToFav
            });
        };
    }


    componentDidMount() {
        fetch("json/voices2.json")
            .then(response => response.json())
            .then(datos => {
                this.setState({
                    voices: datos
                });
            });

        return this.state.voices
    }



    render() {

        function remove(e) {
            const element = e.target;
            element.remove(e);
        }

        function removeFavs() {
            let elem = document.getElementById('favs-row');
            elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
            return false;
        }


        return (

            <React.Fragment>
                <Container>
                    <Row className="header-content">
                        <div className="free-solo-2-demo">
                            <Autocomplete
                                id="combo-box-demo"
                                autoComplete
                                options={this.state.voices.map((option) => option.name)}
                                style={{ width: 300, backgroundColor: '#000000' }}
                                includeInputInList
                                size="small"
                                renderInput={(params) =>
                                    <TextField {...params}
                                               label={<SearchIcon style={{color: 'darkgrey'}}  />}
                                               variant="outlined"
                                               InputProps={{ ...params.InputProps, type: 'search' }}
                                    />}
                            />
                        </div>
                    </Row>
                    <h3 className="fav-title">FAVOURITES VOICES</h3>
                    {this.props.list.map(datos => (
                    <Row className="voices-favs-list" id="favs-row" onClick={remove} >
                            <Col xs lg="2" key={datos.name} id="voices-favs-list" align="center"  >
                                <li
                                    className="col-sm-3 card-list"
                                    id="card-icon-image"
                                    key={datos.id}
                                    style={{listStyleType: 'none'}}
                                    onClick={removeFavs} >
                                     <img
                                         className="card-img-list"
                                         src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/imagenes/${datos.icon}`}
                                         alt={datos.name}
                                     />
                                     <p style={{marginTop: '1rem' }}>{datos.name}</p>
                                </li>
                            </Col>
                    </Row>
                    ))}
                </Container>
                <Container className="container-1" >
                    <Row>
                        <h3 className="pro-title">PRO VOICES</h3>

                        {this.state.voices.map(datos => (

                            <Col xs lg="2" key={datos.id} className="col-sm-3 voices-list" align="center" onClick={() => this.props.clicked(datos)}>
                                <div className="card-list" onSelect={this.onSelect} id="card-list" >
                                    <span className="card-fav-img"/>
                                    <img
                                        onToggle={this.onToggle}
                                        alt={datos.name}
                                        className="card-img-list"
                                        //onClick={() => this.props.clicked(datos)}
                                        src={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/imagenes/${datos.icon}`}
                                    />
                                    <span style={{marginTop: '1rem' }}>{datos.name}</span>
                                </div>
                            </Col>
                        ))}
                    </Row>
                </Container>
            </React.Fragment>
        );
    }
}´´´


<!---- Archivo JSON ------>


[
  {
    "id": "2x1",
    "name": "2x1",
    "icon": "VoicesVoiceIcon01.png",
    "tags": [
      "misc"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "8bits",
    "name": "8bits",
    "icon": "VoicesVoiceIcon02.png",
    "tags": [
      "devices"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "adult-to-children",
    "name": "Adult to children",
    "icon": "VoicesVoiceIcon03.png",
    "tags": [
      "human"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "alien",
    "name": "Alien",
    "icon": "VoicesVoiceIcon01.png",
    "tags": [
      "robotic"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "android",
    "name": "Android",
    "icon": "VoicesVoiceIcon02.png",
    "tags": [
      "robotic"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "aphonic",
    "name": "Aphonic",
    "icon": "VoicesVoiceIcon03.png",
    "tags": [
      "human"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "baby",
    "name": "Baby",
    "icon": "VoicesVoiceIcon01.png",
    "tags": [
      "human"
    ]
  }
]


´´´
```

Comment: Por favor edita tu pregunta y agrega un ejemplo del contenido del JSON.

Comment: Tienes razón @Triby se me había olvidado meter el json para que se vea como son los datos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En vez de buscar un item aleatorio por id, puedes generar un número random que esté entre `0` y `arr.length` (longitud del array que contiene los favoritos).

Y usar ese número random como `index` para seleccionar un item del array de favoritos.
Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como lo podrías hacer, lo hecho en Javascript Vanilla sin usar `react`, pero puedes aplicar lo mismo a tu componente.

La función `getRandomItem` es recursiva para evitar items repetidos.

```js
const data = [
  {
    "id": "2x1",
    "name": "2x1",
    "icon": "VoicesVoiceIcon01.png",
    "tags": [
      "misc"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "8bits",
    "name": "8bits",
    "icon": "VoicesVoiceIcon02.png",
    "tags": [
      "devices"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "adult-to-children",
    "name": "Adult to children",
    "icon": "VoicesVoiceIcon03.png",
    "tags": [
      "human"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "alien",
    "name": "Alien",
    "icon": "VoicesVoiceIcon01.png",
    "tags": [
      "robotic"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "android",
    "name": "Android",
    "icon": "VoicesVoiceIcon02.png",
    "tags": [
      "robotic"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "aphonic",
    "name": "Aphonic",
    "icon": "VoicesVoiceIcon03.png",
    "tags": [
      "human"
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "baby",
    "name": "Baby",
    "icon": "VoicesVoiceIcon01.png",
    "tags": [
      "human"
    ]
  }
];

const state = {
  randomFav: null,
  favorites: data
}

// Como Math.random genera un número decimal pues le aplico Math.floor para redondear al menor entero más cercano
const random = () => Math.floor(Math.random() * state.favorites.length)

function getRandomItem() {
  const index = random();
  
  if (state.randomFav === index) {
    return getRandomItem();
  }
  state.randomFav = index;
  return state.favorites[index];
}

console.log(getRandomItem())
```

Comment: Voy a probarlo dentro de mi componente y adaptar el código para mi app. Si todo funciona marco la respuesta como solución. Muchas Gracias @hawks